# Is there a way to combine namespaces in output?

Tags: typescript

I'm just kind of trying to get the feel for TypeScript, and I'm wanting to separate my code into multiple files. I've been [looking at the documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#splitting-across-files), and I found what I think I'm looking for with namespaces. I'm using the example in the documentation here:

Validation.ts:

```
namespace Validation {
    export interface StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string): boolean;
    }
}
```

LettersOnlyValidator.ts:

```
/// <reference path="Validation.ts" />
namespace Validation {
    const lettersRegexp = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    export class LettersOnlyValidator implements StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string) {
            return lettersRegexp.test(s);
        }
    }
}
```

ZipCodeValidator.ts:

```
/// <reference path="Validation.ts" />
namespace Validation {
    const numberRegexp = /^[0-9]+$/;
    export class ZipCodeValidator implements StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string) {
            return s.length === 5 && numberRegexp.test(s);
        }
    }
}
```

I follow the example and using `tsc` I output to a single file. TypeScript generates this:

```
var Validation;
(function (Validation) {
    var lettersRegexp = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    var LettersOnlyValidator = (function () {
        function LettersOnlyValidator() {
        }
        LettersOnlyValidator.prototype.isAcceptable = function (s) {
            return lettersRegexp.test(s);
        };
        return LettersOnlyValidator;
    }());
    Validation.LettersOnlyValidator = LettersOnlyValidator;
})(Validation || (Validation = {}));
var Validation;
(function (Validation) {
    var numberRegexp = /^[0-9]+$/;
    var ZipCodeValidator = (function () {
        function ZipCodeValidator() {
        }
        ZipCodeValidator.prototype.isAcceptable = function (s) {
            return s.length === 5 && numberRegexp.test(s);
        };
        return ZipCodeValidator;
    }());
    Validation.ZipCodeValidator = ZipCodeValidator;
})(Validation || (Validation = {}));
var strings = ["Hello", "98052", "101"];
var validators = {};
validators["ZIP code"] = new Validation.ZipCodeValidator();
validators["Letters only"] = new Validation.LettersOnlyValidator();
for (var _i = 0, strings_1 = strings; _i < strings_1.length; _i++) {
    var s = strings_1[_i];
    for (var name_1 in validators) {
        console.log("\"" + s + "\" " + (validators[name_1].isAcceptable(s) ? " matches " : " does not match ") + name_1);
    }
}
```

This works, but is quite ugly. Is there a way to get it to combine those two blocks into one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> . Is there a way to get it to combine those two blocks into one

Nope. TypeScript tries to be agnostic about how your JavaScript will execute e.g. with `--out` it doesn't do any special ordering of the files.

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/outFile.html